# Build opencv_contrib sample executables on Linux (OpenCV 3.0.0-alpha)

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, build, cmake

System: VM Ubuntu 14.04 x64

**Summary**:
I'm building OpenCV 3.0.0-dev with the contrib modules from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib but I can't get the executables from opencv_contrib.

---

I was trying to follow this tutorial about the tracking API: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/tracking/doc/tracking.html

Somewhere it says: *To see how API works, try tracker demo: https://github.com/lenlen/opencv/blob/tracking_api/samples/cpp/tracker.cpp*

But that's a forked old repository (by user *lenlen*), not the official repository. [In the recent versions](http://opencv.org/opencv-3-0-alpha.html) (with the new repos) it seems like that file is not in that location anymore but in:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/tracking/samples/tracker.cpp

**The problem**:
I'm being able to build OpenCV without errors, but I can't see how to build that executable file from opencv_contrib, or where is it getting located.

**I've tried**:

- Setting up `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` with: `cmake -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules ..`
- Setting up `INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES` with: `cmake -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON ..`
- Entering in `opencv_contrib`, creating and entering into a "`build`" directory and from there executing: "`cmake ..`" ...but that gives errors (no CMakeLists.txt).
- Entering in "`opencv_contrib/modules/tracking/`", creating and entering into a "`build`" directory and executing "`cmake ..`" (because there's a CMakeLists.txt inside of the `tracking` directory). But that also gives errors.
- Entering in "`opencv_contrib/modules/tracking/samples/`" and executing "`g++ tracker.cpp`", but that also gives errors.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. It was a silly mistake.

I was setting up `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` as: `cmake -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules ..`

But my working directory was "`opencv/build/`" (I was in a directory "`build`" inside of opencv and the "`opencv_contrib`" was in the same directory as "`opencv`"), so that variable should have been: `cmake -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules ..`